# How do I update a Google Map Engine Table?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-engine

I have a table in Google Maps Engine that I would like to update dynamically with JavaScript in a Google Site.  I've found [**this**](https://developers.google.com/maps-engine/documentation/reference/v1/tables/features/batchInsert) help page that explains how to append features to an existing table, but I'm struggling to figure out how to modify the code so that it will update the table instead of append to it.  I believe I specifically need to modify the `processResponse` and `processErrorResponse` functions.  However, I'm fairly new to JavaScript/jQuery/JSON, and I'm not exactly sure how to determine what I should have instead of `#insert-table-features-response`.  Is there someone here that could explain that to me?

**Edit:** To put it another way, how can I make the request shown below with JavaScript?

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/mapsengine/v1/tables/{YOUR_TABLE_KEY}/features/batchPatch?key={YOUR_API_KEY}

Content-Type:  application/json
Authorization:  Bearer {. . .}
X-JavaScript-User-Agent:  Google APIs Explorer

{
 "features": [
  {
   "geometry": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [
     -82,
     35
    ]
   },
   "properties": {
    "Lat": 35,
    "Long": -82,
    "Name": "6:41:13 AM 11/27/14",
    "gx_id": "123ABC456DEF7890"
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than try and squeeze this into a comment on jpatokal's answer, I'll throw it in an answer.

As they said, you will want to use the `batchPatch` request, rather than `batchInsert`.  Check out the docs here: https://developers.google.com/maps-engine/documentation/reference/v1/tables/features/batchPatch

If you're using the JS provided in the docs, then the code on page you linked to includes this function:

```
function insertTableFeatures(tableId) {
  doRequest({
    path: '/mapsengine/v1/tables/' + tableId + '/features/batchInsert',
    method: 'POST',
    body: {
      features: cities
    },
    processResponse: function(response) {
      $('#insert-table-features-response').text(
          JSON.stringify(response, null, 2));
    },
    processErrorResponse: function(response) {
      $('#insert-table-features-response').text('Error response:\n\n' +
          JSON.stringify(response, null, 2));
    }
  });
}
```

You will want to change the `path` from `batchInsert` to `batchPatch` and update the `body: { ... }`. You can replace it with the body of the HTTP request you provided like so:

```
function updateTableFeatures(tableId) {
  doRequest({
    path: '/mapsengine/v1/tables/' + tableId + '/features/batchPatch',
    method: 'POST',
    body: {
     "features": [
      {
       "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
         -82,
         35
        ]
       },
       "properties": {
        "Lat": 35,
        "Long": -82,
        "Name": "6:41:13 AM 11/27/14",
        "gx_id": "123ABC456DEF7890"
       }
      }
     ]
    },
    processResponse: function(response) {
      // You'll probably want to change these too
      $('#insert-table-features-response').text(
          JSON.stringify(response, null, 2));
    },
    processErrorResponse: function(response) {
      // You'll probably want to change these too
      $('#insert-table-features-response').text('Error response:\n\n' +
          JSON.stringify(response, null, 2));
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`batchInsert`, true to the name, only inserts new features.  Try [`batchPatch`](https://developers.google.com/maps-engine/documentation/reference/v1/tables/features/batchPatch) instead.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I didn't make myself clear. I understand I need to use `batchPatch` (I have the request all set up the way I want with the API explorer), but I don't know how to modify the JavaScript shown on the `batchInsert` help page to execute the request I want instead of the one that's shown. I'll try to modify the question to make that more clear.